# Is there a better performing functional version of this iterative algorithm in C#?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, iteration

I was hoping to figure out a way to write the below in a functional style with extension functions.  Ideally this functional style would perform well compared to the iterative/loop version.  I'm guessing that there isn't a way.  Probably because of the many additional function calls and stack allocations, etc.

Fundamentally I think the pattern which is making it troublesome is that it both calculates a value to use for the Predicate and then needs that calculated value again as part of the resulting collection.

```
// This is what is passed to each function.
// Do not assume the array is in order.
var a = (0).To(999999).ToArray().Shuffle();

// Approx times in release mode (on my machine):
// Functional is avg 20ms per call
// Iterative is avg 5ms per call
// Linq is avg 14ms per call

private static List<int> Iterative(int[] a)
{
    var squares = new List<int>(a.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        var n = a[i];

        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            int square = n * n;

            if (square < 1000000)
            {
                squares.Add(square);
            }
        }
    }

    return squares;
}

private static List<int> Functional(int[] a)
{
    return
    a
        .Where(x => x % 2 == 0 && x * x < 1000000)
        .Select(x => x * x)
        .ToList();
}

private static List<int> Linq(int[] a)
{
    var squares =
        from num in a
        where num % 2 == 0 && num * num < 1000000
        select num * num;

    return squares.ToList();
}
```

Comment: `Iterative` adds `n` to `squares`, not `square`. Is that intended?

Comment: Instead of doing `n*n`, compute `sqrt(1000000)` first (to a constant/variable) and use that in the comparison. I am not going to say it will do anything for the performance here, but it is possible to invert the math in certain cases like this. (Assumes `n` is positive.)

Comment: @dtb You are right, my mistake.  It should collect the squares.  That's what was intended.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to Konrad's suggestion. This avoids the double calculation, but also avoids even calculating the square when it doesn't have to:

```
return a.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
        .Select(x => x * x)
        .Where(square => square < 1000000)
        .ToList();
```

Personally, I wouldn't sweat the difference in performance until I'd seen it be *significant* in a larger context.

(I'm assuming that this is just an example, by the way. Normally you'd possibly compute the square root of 1000000 once and then just compare `n` with that, to shave off a few milliseconds. It does require two comparisons or an `Abs` operation though, of course.)

EDIT: Note that a more functional version would avoid using `ToList` at all. Return `IEnumerable<int>` instead, and let the caller transform it into a `List<T>` *if they want to*. If they don't, they don't take the hit. If they only want the first 5 values, they can call `Take(5)`. That laziness *could* be a big performance win over the original version, depending on the context.

Comment: Much better, should be a factor 2 faster than mine on average.

Comment: Darn I meant it to collect he square.  That slight logic problem doesn't change the overall idea though.  I'm going to add the times that I found for various versions.

Answer (score 2):

Just solving your problem of the double calculation:

```
return (from x in a
        let sq = x * x
        where x % 2 == 0 && sq < 1000000
        select sq).ToList();
```

That said, I’m not sure that this will lead to much performance improvement. Is the functional variant actually noticeably faster than the iterative one? The code offers quite a lot of potential for automated optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

How about some parallel processing?  Or does the solution have to be LINQ (which I consider to be slow).

```
var squares = new List<int>(a.Length);

Parallel.ForEach(a, n =>
{
  if(n < 1000 && n % 2 == 0) squares.Add(n * n);             
}
```

The Linq version would be:

```
return a.AsParallel()
  .Where(n => n < 1000 && n % 2 == 0)  
  .Select(n => n * n)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a functional solution that will be completely on-par with the iterative solution performance-wise. In my timings (see below) the 'functional' implementation from the OP appears to be around twice as slow as the iterative implementation.

Micro-benchmarks like this one are prone to all manner of issues. A common tactic in dealing with variability problems is to repeatedly call the method being timed and compute an average time per call - like this:

```
// from main
Time(Functional, "Functional", a);    
Time(Linq, "Linq", a);    
Time(Iterative, "Iterative", a);
// ...

static int reps = 1000;
private static List<int> Time(Func<int[],List<int>> func, string name, int[] a)
{
    var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    List<int> ret = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < reps; ++i)
    {
        ret = func(a);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0} per call timings - {1} ticks, {2} ms",
        name,
        sw.ElapsedTicks/(double)reps,
        sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/(double)reps);
    return ret;
}
```

Here are the timings from one session:

```
Functional per call timings - 46493.541 ticks, 16.945 ms
Linq per call timings - 46526.734 ticks, 16.958 ms
Iterative per call timings - 21971.274 ticks, 8.008 ms
```

There are a host of other challenges as well: strobe-effects with the timer use, how and when the just-in-time compiler does its thing, the garbage collector running its collections, the order that competing algorithms are run, the type of cpu, the OS swapping other processes in and out, etc.

I tried my hand at a little optimization. I removed the square from the test (num * num < 1000000) - changing it to (num < 1000) - which seemed safe since there are no negatives in the input - that is, I took the square root of both sides of the inequality. Surprisingly, I got different results as compared to the methods in the OP - there were only 500 items in my optimized output as compared to the 241,849 from the three implementations in the OP implementations. So why the difference? Much of the input when squared overflows 32 bit integers, so those extra 241,349 items came from numbers that when squared overflowed to either negative numbers or numbers under 1 million while still passing our evenness test.

optimized (functional) timing:

```
Optimized per call timings - 16849.529 ticks, 6.141 ms
```

This was one of the functional implementations altered as suggested. It output the 500 items passing the criteria as expected. It is deceptively "faster" only because it output fewer items than the iterative solution.

We can make the original implementations blow up with an OverflowException by adding a checked block around their implementations. Here is a checked block added to the "Iterative" method:

```
private static List<int> Iterative(int[] a)
{
    checked
    {
        var squares = new List<int>(a.Length);

        // rest of method omitted for brevity...

        return squares;
    }
}
```